# Exceeding limit with ifelse statements

Tags: r, regex, if-statement

Problem: I wrote a gigantic piece of code with over 100 `ifelse` statements only to learn that there is a limit on the number of `ifelse` statements: exceeding 50 throws an error. Anyway, I know there is a more efficient way to do what I am trying to do.

Goal: Trying to write a function to recode many variants of strings (see below example) into clear categories (e.g. below). I use `str_detect` to give T/F and then change into the correct category based on response. How can I do this without over 100 `ifelse` statements (I have a lot more categories).

Example:

```
mydf <- data_frame(answer = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T),
                location = c("at home", "home", "in a home", 
"school", "my school", "School", "Work", "work",
                         "working", "work usually"))

loc_function <- function(x) {
  home <- "home"
  school <- "school"
  work <- "work"
  ifelse(str_detect(x, regex(home, ignore_case = T)), "At Home",
     ifelse(str_detect(x, regex(school, ignore_case = T)), "At 
School",
            ifelse(str_detect(x, regex(work, ignore_case = T)), "At 
Work", x)))
}

### Using function to clean up messy strings (and recode first column too) into clean categories
mycleandf <- mydf %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate(answer = ifelse(answer >= 2, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(location = loc_function(location)) %>%
  select(answer, location)

mycleandf

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   answer  location
    <dbl>     <chr>
 1      1   At Home
 2      1   At Home
 3      1   At Home
 4      1 At School
 5      1 At School
 6      1 At School
 7      1   At Work
 8      0   At Work
 9      1   At Work
10      0   At Work
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_switch_statement.htm

Comment: *with over 100 ifelse statements* When you find yourself needing more than a handful of something, you should start thinking about finding a better way. When you reach two handfuls, you should start thinking that you're doing something wrong. If you get to the point you have a wheelbarrow full, **know** that you've totally screwed up and need to seek help. You've hit the dumptruck level.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a case_when statement, or using purr:map() to  map a function to all words to make it title case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your patterns in a named vector, (notice the `Other = ""`, this is a fall back when none of your pattern matches the string):

```
patterns <- c("At Home" = "home", "At School" = "school", "At Work" = "work", "Other" = "")
```

Then loop through the pattern and check if the string contains pattern:

```
match <- sapply(patterns, grepl, mydf$location, ignore.case = T)
```

Finally build up the new column buy checking the name of the matched pattern which is the one you want to replace with, if nothing matches, fall back to Other:

```
mydf$clean_loc <- colnames(match)[max.col(match, ties.method = "first")]
mydf

# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   answer     location clean_loc
#    <int>        <chr>     <chr>
# 1      3      at home   At Home
# 2      3         home   At Home
# 3      3    in a home   At Home
# 4      3       school At School
# 5      2    my school At School
# 6      4       School At School
# 7      5         Work   At Work
# 8      1         work   At Work
# 9      2      working   At Work
#10      1 work usually   At Work
```

Comment: Very helpful. If I had a string that matched both, how could I sort it correctly? EG: "home then at work" I want to classify as "At Work." Adjust  the pattern or the matching logical sequence?

Comment: You can adjust the order of the patterns, put the patterns that you want to prioritize before those you don't. So If you put `At Work` before `At Home`, it will give you `At Work`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nesting the conditions you could execute them sequentially. Using a `for` loop:

```
# Store the find-replace pairs in a data frame

word_map <- data.frame(pattern = c("home", "school", "work"),
                       replacement = c("At Home", "At School", "At Work"), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

word_map
pattern replacement
1    home     At Home
2  school   At School
3    work     At Work

# Iterate through the pairs

for ( i in 1:nrow(word_map) ) {

    pattern     <- word_map$pattern[i]
    replacement <- word_map$replacement[i]

    mydf$location <- ifelse(grepl(pattern, mydf$location, ignore.case = TRUE), replacement, mydf$location)
}

mydf
   answer  location
1       4   At Home
2       4   At Home
3       1   At Home
4       5 At School
5       1 At School
6       2 At School
7       5   At Work
8       2   At Work
9       1   At Work
10      3   At Work
```